# Add Class To Custom Directive Based On Custom Attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code for a button in my application:

```
<a ng-click="addToCart('event', d, type.id, $index )" ng-class="{ 'btn-set': isReady || isWorking || isComplete || hasFailed, 'btn-ready-state': isReady, 'btn-working-state': isWorking && selectedIndex == $index, 'btn-complete-state': isComplete && selectedIndex == $index, 'btn-failed-state': hasFailed }">
    <i ng-if="isReady" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <img ng-src="/images/loading.GIF" class="img" ng-show="isWorking && selectedIndex == $index "></span>
    <i ng-if="isComplete && selectedIndex == $index " class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="text">
        <span ng-if="isReady">Buy Ticket</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Now this is a simple anchor tag styled as a button, what is does is it executes a function when clicked, however since data is being posted to the server via ajax i created several states for each button by defining classes: isReady, isWorking, isComplete, hasFailed.

isReady:
[image: Ready]

isWorking:
[image: Working]

isComplete: 
[image: Complete]

When a button is dormant the default class is isReady, when it is clicked the class and text changes to isWorking, when the operation completes successfully it changes to isComplete, if it fails it changes to hasFailed. However the code above looks a bit much and untidy especially since i have a lot of buttons in my application, repeating code like that seems messy and inefficient to me, so i was thinking of making a directive for it. eg.

```
<action></action>
```

Then I can change the state like this:

```
<action working></action>
```

If I wanted to define an initial text for it:

```
<action ready><b>Initial Text value</b></action>
```

I can create the action directive on my own but adding the attributes and making them apply their respective class is something completely new to me.

Comment: Solved here: [custom-directive-not-showing][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492222/custom-directive-not-showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in this question: [Custom Directive Not Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492222/custom-directive-not-showing).

I had to break it down piece by piece but eventually I got the help I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create directive having state.
2. Create html template for directive.

This will allow you to keep code and html separate.

Js code associated with directive may have **flags or state**. 
And template can be customized as per requirement.

See below code:

```
.directive('action', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'customAction.html'
  };
});
```

Hope this will give you direction.
Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you but actually i can already create a simple directive, my main question was how to make an attribute apply a certain class to that directive. eg. <action ready></action> the "ready" attribute should apply a class of "isReady" to the directive.

Comment: I think that is not required. Still for your ref you can make use of ngClass and ngSwitch. And go ahead.

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question, i may be misunderstanding you so maybe a code sample might help clear things up for me.