# Custom Directive Not Showing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following custom directive inside my ng-repeat:

```
<action ng-click="addToCart('event', d, type.id, $index )" text="Hey!" state="ready"></action>
```

action.js:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('vendor').directive('action', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                text: '@text',
                state: '@state'
            },
            templateUrl: '/js/app/templates/action.html',
            link: ['$http', '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($http, $scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.text = $attrs.text;
            }],
            controller: ['$http', '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($http, $scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.text = $attrs.text;
            }],
            controllerAs: 'action'
        }
    });

}) ();
```

action.html:

```
<a ng-class="{ 'btn-set': isReady || isWorking || isComplete || hasFailed, 'btn-ready-state': isReady, 'btn-working-state': isWorking && selectedIndex == $index, 'btn-complete-state': isComplete && selectedIndex == $index, 'btn-failed-state': hasFailed }">
    <i ng-if="isReady" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <img ng-src="/images/loading.GIF" class="img" ng-show="isWorking && selectedIndex == $index "></span>
    <i ng-if="isComplete && selectedIndex == $index " class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="text">
        <span ng-if="isReady"><% text %></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I have a custom directive **action** with custom attributes **text** and **state**, the text attribute is simply what text displays inside the directive. However my code does not seem to work (i get no errors), i am new to angularjs so i suppose i am making some rookie mistake somewhere.

Note: I changed **{{ }}** to **<% %>** so it doesn't conflict with my laravel blade templating

Comment: No error in console or network tabs of Chrome Dev Tools / Firebug?

Comment: No errors are being shown.

Comment: What do you see in the elements tab? I'd guess the directive content is there but not shown as the variables in your `ng-show` and `ng-if` expressions don't exist in the directive's scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your strings to be wrapped in `''`, and use `{{}}` inside your `action.html`:

```
<action ng-click="addToCart('event', d, type.id, $index )" text="'Hey!'" state="'ready'"></action>
```

And in your HTML:

```
<span ng-if="isReady">{{ text }}</span>
```

And by the way, when your scope variables are the same name as the attribute you don't need to mention it, and you can just do:

```
scope: {
     text: '@',
     state: '@'
 },
```

**Edit:** As squiroid pointed out in his question, I think your link/controller functions are a bit off. First, you don't need to use the `[`, since those are there to fix injections. You can simply do:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   //now you have scope.text, you don't need to assign from attrs
},
```

The `$http` service should be injected to the directive itself, not the link/controller function, like this:

```
.directive('action', ['$http', function($http) {
   ...
}]
```

Also, there's no need to overwrite the text in your link/controller. You just need to use `scope.text` since it's there from your isolated scope declaration.

Comment: Okay, your post helped me out a bit but i am having an issue here, $scope.isReady is being set by another controller/service but my directive does not seem to notice this.

Comment: @user3718908 According to your HTML, `isReady` is a variable on scope, but you haven't declared it. You need to connect it to something.. how are you setting it?

Comment: Is ready is declared in another controller that is also included on the same page it's value can either be true or false.

Comment: Yes you either filled it with parent of the directive or define the directive itself.

Comment: @user3718908 You used isolated scope for your directive. It only knows `text` & `state`, no other parameter. So it will be undefined at all times.

Comment: Just add `isReady: '&'`, isWorking: '&',` etc. to the `scope` option. Try it [in a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6j4kmzzJ3UBYuROdyj5Q?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i noticed everthing is fine except two thing

```
<span ng-if="isReady">{{ text }}</span>
```

Second the directive link function here order matters first is scope ,second is element,thir attribute and last is controller of parent.And if you want to use $http in link you must inject it in directive itself not in link beacuse link is not filled by DI .

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.text = $attrs.text;
            },
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Okay 1 thing though $scope.isReady is being set from another controller/service, but my directive does not seem to notice this, is there a reason for that?

Comment: here $scope is alias you can name it anything like abc or etc and it is filled by the parent of directive if it doesn't have isolated scope.

Comment: Okay so right now what i would really like to know is how i can access isReady from my directive.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
transclude: true,
```

and
    scope: {
                    text: '=',
                    state: '='
                }

then your